# CanCan: Can do RUD but not C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cancan

I'm trying to allow a user to read, update, or destroy a form that they themselves have created. I'm having some trouble.

In my ability.rb, I have

```
can [:update, :read, :destroy], Form.where(:user => user)
```

given that user is an attribute of the form. I can get the forms (and the responses to the forms) to display when I don't have this line in my ability class, but I obviously do not want people to be able to delete the forms of other users. I have already called

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

to invoke CanCan in the controller. Currently I have this error:

```
The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition. The checking code cannot be determined for :index Form(id: integer, user_id: integer, policy: boolean, two_adult: boolean, training: boolean, attribute_name: boolean, attribute: boolean, agree_to_form: boolean, user_signature: string, signature_date: date, printed_date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

(Changed some names for privacy. I'm also using Devise, by the way, if this changes anything)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Would a solution such as...

```
can :read, Form do |form|
    form.user == user
  end
```

be a possibility?

Edit2: My view...

```
<% @forms.each do |form| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= form.user %></td>
    <td><%= form.policy %></td>
    <td><%= form.two_adult %></td>
    <td><%= form.training %></td>
    <td><%= form.other_attribute %></td>
    <td><%= form.attribute %></td>
    <td><%= form.agree_to_covenant %></td>
    <td><%= form.user_signature %></td>
    <td><%= form.signature_date %></td>
    <td><%= form.printed_date %></td>

    <% if can? :read, @form %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', form %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :update, @form %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_form_path(form) %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :destroy, @form %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', form, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I also noticed upon refreshing the page that the user hash changes each time. This is problematic.

Edit3: Pertinent Ability.rb info...

```
if user.is_camper?
  can :read, Camp
  can :read, Payment, Payment.where(:user => user)
  can :create, Payment
  can :read, Form, :user => user.id
```

[Here is a visual of what happens too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNxIF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last variant (defined through block) should work.

See examples [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions).

In your case you can define through hash - it is simpler

```
can :read, Form, :user_id => user.id
```

And according to [this point](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#the-can-method) you can separately define `:read`, `:create`, `:update` and `:destroy`

Code on the page:
You iterate by form, so you should check ability on each of them (NOT for one `@form`)

```
<% @forms.each do |form| %>
  ...
  <% if can? :read, form %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  <% if can? :update, form %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Changes in ability:

```
can :read, Form # user can read all forms (not only own)
can [:create, :update, :destroy], Form, :user_id => user.id # it is better to use `user_id` instead of `user`
```

It is just one variant that should work properly but it is not tested by me :)

Comment: See, that's the thing. It should work, but it doesn't. Currently it just hides all options, and I've even created a form with the current user. I'm wondering if it even notices that the current user created a form. Also, :user is the attribute in my form so I changed the code to reflect that but alas no luck.

Comment: As I understand you have some troubles on the page... Post your view

Comment: Why `if can? :read, @form` when it should be `if can? :read, form`. And could you explain what does it mean "I also noticed upon refreshing the page that the user hash changes each time". if it is about defining ability post your `ability.rb` as well

Comment: Won't the first statement return true in most cases since it's asking if it can read an instance of the form, rather than the specific form? Or am I misled? I will edit again for clarity purposes.

Comment: see updated answer. it is just a variant (I hope it will work) which you can modify according your business logic

Comment: THANK YOU! This totally fixed the problem for me. You are absolutely right in terms of editing forms, you have to iterate through them. Your help is very much appreciated.